# Typeface.js not rendering fonts in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, typeface.js

just wodering if anyone has experience with Typeface.js ( http://typeface.neocracy.org ) and fixing issues of the font not being rendered in Internet Explorer ( 6, 7 and 8 ).

The font renders in Firefox and Safari fine, hover nothing is displayed in the Explorers. The font is not installed locally so I know that the script is working.

I am using the typical usage of

```
<div class="typeface-js" style="font-family: Optimer">
    TEXT HERE
  </div>
```

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like typeface.neocracy.org only gives you the TrueType font (.ttf) and not the Embedded OpenType (.eot) that's used by IE.  Try passing the Optimer font through [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and you should have better luck.